# Find out if a variable is a martingale (discrete time)

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

Let X be a stochastic variable on a finite, filtered probability space.
If
$$
M_1(t) = E(X| \mathcal{F}_t)
$$
Is $M_1(t)$ a martingale?

I have a lot of trouble checking if variables are martingales or not. I know about the $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ notation, and I am allowed to use this to answer the question.

I am pretty sure you need to use the tower law to solve this problem, which says that

$$
E(E(X_u|\mathcal{F}_t)|\mathcal{F_d}) = E(X_u|\mathcal{F}_d)\text{ } whenever\text{  } d \leq t \leq u
$$

But I just dont see how its done? Can someone help me out? What is the general method to find out if a variable is a martingale or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $s\le t$, we have by the tower rule :
$$\mathbb E[M_1(t)\mid \mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F_t]\mid\mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal F_s]=M_1(s)$$
Furthermore, since for all $t$ we have  $\mathbb E[M_1(t)]=\mathbb E[X]$ and $X$ is integrable because the probability space is finite, then $(M_1(t))_t$ is integrable and hence a martingale. This form of martingale is called a closed martingale.

Comment: Thank you so much. So in general the approach is to take the conditional mean of M, conditioned on F_s (<=t). Then check if that is equal to M(s), and if not, its not a martingale?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. Of course, you mustn't forget that the process in question is integrable.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much!